# Hashing algorithm and library used in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

does hyperledger fabric use sha256 for hashing?

And also can someone please tell me which library is used for hashing in hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Fabric uses SHA256 for hashing.
The Fabric core is implemented in Go, so it uses the language's built in [crypto/sha256](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/) package.